# How can I create an auto increment number that resets every month

Tags: formula-field

I need to create a custom field that needs to contain the following values:

year.month.autoincrement

autoincrement needs to be reset every month,

example:
2021.1.012
2021.1.001

how can I accomplish this?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do:
An object to store the last number used;
A trigger to get the number and sum +1 in this object;
A batch to set 0 when the month starts.
What did you already try?

Comment: @mPeixoto is it possible to do this without using apex?

Comment: You could try: 1. Create an object to store the last number; 2. Create a workflow rule time dependence to set to 0 again; 3. Create a Process builder to get the number and sum + 1.